# Difference between JSON structures

Tags: arrays, json, object

I'm learning `JSON` and its structure. I have read documentation but still feel a bit confused on the the different structures and what they mean and how they are set up.

Let's take this for an example:

```
[
    {"firstName":"Jocke","job":"developer"},
    {"firstName":"Anna","job":"skydiver"},
    {"firstName":"Peter","job":"pilot"}
]
```

Now, this is valid. Is this counted as an object? The reason I ask is because of the brackets `[]` that I normally associate with arrays. So if (I assume) this is an object, then is the code below an array?

```
[ "value1", "value2", "value3" ]
```

The difference being not using `{}` and `:`

Now if I'm right on the two first (object, array), then I'm on track, but there is still one thing I don't quite grasp. I have seen this structure as well:

```
{ "people":
    [
        {"firstName":"Jocke","job":"developer"},
        {"firstName":"Anna","job":"skydiver"},    
        {"firstName":"Peter","job":"pilot"}
    ]
}
```

This is also valid, and I assume it's still an object. What confuse me is `"people"`. What is that in the context of an object, why is it there, and why would I need it?

Comment: arrays are special type of object

Comment: "People" is an Array. It indicates an array of objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As mdn says:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

> The JavaScript Array class is a global object that is used in the
>   construction of arrays; which are high-level, list-like objects.

It is an array of objects:

```
[
    {"firstName":"Jocke","job":"developer"},
    {"firstName":"Anna","job":"skydiver"},
    {"firstName":"Peter","job":"pilot"}
]
```

Array of strings:

```
[ "value1", "value2", "value3" ]
```

An object with property `people` which contains array:

```
{ "people":
    [
        {"firstName":"Jocke","job":"developer"},
        {"firstName":"Anna","job":"skydiver"},    
        {"firstName":"Peter","job":"pilot"}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Ah, yes, so "people" is the key object with the object values in the array that follows. Got it. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First one is an array of objects.

```
[
    {"firstName":"Jocke","job":"developer"},
    {"firstName":"Anna","job":"skydiver"},
    {"firstName":"Peter","job":"pilot"}
]
```

The one you showed in the end is a Json object which has one Object which is `People` and `People` itself is an Array of objects.

```
{ "people":
    [
        {"firstName":"Jocke","job":"developer"},
        {"firstName":"Anna","job":"skydiver"},    
        {"firstName":"Peter","job":"pilot"}
    ]
}
```

> An array is treated as a special object and is a first class citizen
>   in Json.

In short, Every place where you can use Objects, You can also use array of Objects.